# firefox Disable right click Fill password

Tags: firefox, right-click, loginstatus

I need to disable right click fill password in firefox.

Is there any way to do it?

Thank you in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32bZN.png)

Comment: Why would you need that? Messing with anything like that just _decreases_ security. For example, my password manager not automatically suggesting my login data on a site I know I was using it on previously, would easily alert me to the fact that I have wandered onto a phishing site. Leave this decision to me, the user - everything else is just you making things worse.

Comment: Hello Thank you for your response. My needs is specific, I will explain that: i would like in specific server that no one can see the stored password.

Comment: Then don’t store it, or don’t let anyone else use this particular Firefox profile ...?

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the Firefox **about:config**, and change the setting **signon.autofillForms** to **false**.  That should disable the "Fill Login" context menu item.

Comment: In my case, I wanted to disable the item because I use LastPass, and I found it redundant and wanted less clutter in the context menu.

Comment: This didn't disable the "Fill Password" item in FF59.